# How to update Firebase user profile on sign in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Currently, I update FirebaseUser profile **after** sign in, can I do it as **part** of sign-in parameters? i.e as an atomic operation?

The reason is that I want to avoid handling error of profile not updated correctly e.g. not a stable internet connection or app crash

I tried to update the profile name before the actual sign-in, hoping it will take it from the previous but it did not work

Please note the user before sign-in is anonymous and its uid might be different from the final signed-in user

This is my current code

```
private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity()) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                updateProfile()
            } else {
                codeError()
            }
        }
}

private fun updateProfile() {
    val profile = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("user name")
        .build()

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.updateProfile(profile)

    goBackToMain()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I update Firebase user profile after sign in

That's the right thing to do. When you call `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential()`, a [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object is created. Once this object is created, it can be updated.

> I tried to update the profile name before the actual sign-in, hoping it will take it from the previous but it did not work

Indeed it's the expected behavior because, before the sign-in, the FirebaseUser object:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
```

Will return null, meaning that the user is not signed in. There is no way you can update an object that that is not initialized and holds the value on null.

> Please note the user before sign-in is anonymous and its uid might be different from the final signed-in user.

It won't unless the user signs-out or uninstalls the app. When you link an anonymous account with a Provider, for example with Google, the UID of the user remains the same, meaning that:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.uid
```

Is the same as before you linked the account.